# How to convert a Map of Map to Json

Tags: java, json

I have a Map syntax like `Map<String,Map<String,String>>` the data can be any dummy details i need the json created as below which has map of map data.

```
“<row id 1>”:{
 “record_id”:”<unique record id>”,
              “field”:[
                       {
                        “<1234>”  :”<value in field 1>”,
                        “<field 2>”  :”<value in field 2>” ,
                        “<field 3>”  :”<value in field 3>” ,
                        “<field n>”  :”<value in field n>”                      
                       }
                        ], 
                   },

      “<row id 2>”:{
            “record_id”:”<unique record id>”,
“field”:[
                       {
                        “<field 1>”  :”<value in field 1>”,
                        “<field 2>”  :”<value in field 2>” ,
                        “<field 3>”  :”<value in field 3>” ,
                        “<field n>”  :”<value in field n>”                      
                       }
                        ], 

                   },
```

How can use a jSONoBJECT here ?

Comment: FWIW Note that a more sophisticated Java-to/from-JSON APIs such as Jackson can accomplish this in one simple line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this? http://www.androidsnippets.com/transform-a-map-to-a-json-object

Comment: Yes similar to this,but i have map of map ,i am actually not getting first how to set data into map of map and use jsonobject

Comment: Facing an issue with this example at http://www.androidsnippets.com/transform-a-map-to-a-json-object in line Map m = (Map) pairs.getValue(); --cannot cast string to map

Comment: The example is converting a `Map<String,Map<String,String>>` to a JSONObject. The outer map is stored as JSONObject.put(String,JSONObject), and the inner JSONObject is (String,String). The `Map` that is passed into `getJSON(Map)` is `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`. That's why the pairs.getValue() is cast into a Map, it's not a String.

Comment: I am facing issue in cast for this Map :Map outerMap = new HashMap();
  Map rowIdMap = new HashMap();
  Map fieldMap = new HashMap();
  fieldMap.put("id1", "usa");
  fieldMap.put("id2", "12");
  fieldMap.put("id3", "13");
  rowIdMap.put("field", fieldMap);
  rowIdMap.put("record_id", "12");
  outerMap.put("rowId", rowIdMap);

Comment: Can you please let me know what is the problem in the above map ?having a cast error while using the above map

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, First of all, you have a rowIdMap that has a (String,Map), and then a (String, String). Of course you're going to have problems casting that. Then you have fieldMap inside rowIdMap, and rowIdMap inside outerMap. That is **NOT** `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`

Comment: Please quote the relevant part of the link in your answer next time. It's now a dead link.